# Update array and change the view, AureliaJS

Tags: aurelia

Just got into AureliaJS, very interesting framework.
I'm trying to implement a simple tic tac toe game but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

App.js:

```
export class App {
    constructor() {
        this.heading = 'Tic-Tac-Toe';
        this.board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
        this.playerOne = 'X';
        this.playerTwo = 'O';
        this.currentPlayer = this.playerOne;
    }

    makeTurn(index) {
        if(this.board[index] === "") {
            this.board[index] = this.currentPlayer;
            this.currentPlayer = this.currentPlayer === this.playerOne ? this.playerTwo : this.playerOne;
            console.log(this.board);
        }
    }
}
```

App.html:

```
<template>
    <require from="style.css"></require>
    <h1>${heading}</h1>

    <div class="board">
        <div repeat.for="sqare of board" class="sqare" click.trigger="makeTurn({$index}.$index)">${sqare}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

If I try to change for example the heading variable in the makeTurn function it does change the heading so I don't get why update an array doesn't update the view as well.

Comment: can you try click.trigger="makeTurn($index)" and console.log('maketurn', index) in the maketurn function to see if that fires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is expected in fact (https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/431)
One quick way to fix this is creating a shallow copy of the array

```
this.board = this.board.slice()
```